# C RPC Server malloc memory corruption

Tags: c, rpc

I'm doing a RPC program and in the server side I'm getting memory corrupted but I don't know exactly why, all the functions works fine but this one.

I tried first with strndup and then change it for malloc and strcpy on the struct variables, but both don't work.

EDIT: Tried strdup as well, still memory corruption

***EDIT FIXED: The problem was the malloc on "persona", the sizeof was wrong.***

Structs

```c
struct facturar {
    int idReserva;
    int idReg;
    int idPlaza;
    int fila;
    int asiento;
    char *nombre;
    char *dni;
    struct facturar *siguiente;
};
typedef struct facturar facturar;

struct datos_facturacion {
    struct facturar *lista;
};
typedef struct datos_facturacion datos_facturacion;
```

```c
static datos_facturacion result;
char buffer[200];
struct facturar * persona;
xdr_free((xdrproc_t)xdr_datos_facturacion,(char *)&result);
// ...
f = fopen("DatosReservas", "r");
    f2 = fopen("Ffacturacion", "a");
    idr = argp->idVuelo;

while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), f) != NULL){
        c2 = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
        strcpy(c2, buffer);
        c = strtok_r(c2, ":", &c1);
        printf("%d-%d-\n", idr, atoi(c));
        if(idr == atoi(c)){
            persona = malloc(sizeof(persona));;
            persona->idReserva = idr;
            fprintf(f2, "%d:", idr);
            c = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &c1);
            printf("%s\n", c);
            persona->idReg = idreg;
            fprintf(f2, "%d:", idreg);
            c = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &c1);
            printf("%s\n", c);
            persona->idPlaza = atoi(c);
            fprintf(f2, "%d:", atoi(c));
            if(asAsignado == asiento){
                fAsignada = fAsignada + 1;
                asAsignado = 1;
            }
            persona->fila = fAsignada;
            fprintf(f2, "%d:", fAsignada);
            persona->asiento = asAsignado;
            fprintf(f2, "%d:", asAsignado);
            c = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &c1);
            printf("Cadena antes de Malloc: %s\n", c);
            persona->nombre = malloc(strlen(c) + 1);
            strcpy(persona->nombre, c);
            fprintf(f2, "%s:", c);
            c = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &c1);
            printf("Cadena dps de malloc %s\n", persona->nombre);
            printf("Cadena antes de Malloc2: %s\n", c);
            persona->dni = malloc(strlen(c) + 1);
            strcpy(persona->dni, c);
            printf("Cadena despues de Malloc2: %s\n", persona->dni);
            fprintf(f2, "%s\n", persona->dni);
            persona->siguiente = result.lista;
            result.lista = persona;
        }
        free(c2);
    }
    fclose(f);
    fclose(f2);
return &result;
```

In the last iteration I got the error in the last malloc

> Error :
>   malloc(): memory corruption
>   aborted (core dumped)
>
> New output to test :

Cadena before of Malloc: Alberto // printing "c" of strtok_r
Cadena after of malloc Alberto // printing persona->nombre after malloc
Cadena before of Malloc2: 33445511J
Cadena after of Malloc2: 33445511J //printing persona->dni after malloc

Cadena before of Malloc: Juan
Cadena after of malloc Juan
Cadena before of Malloc2: 92312321C
Cadena after of Malloc2: 92312321C

Cadena antes of Malloc: Pepe Macias
Cadena dps of malloc Pepe Macias
Cadena antes of Malloc2: 39421294D
Cadena despues of Malloc2: 39421294D

Cadena before of Malloc: Ignacio Gutierrez Povedilla
Cadena after of malloc Ignacio Gutierrez Povedilla
Cadena before of Malloc2: 92123421Y
malloc(): memory corruption
Abortado (`core' generado)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    c2 = malloc(strlen(buffer));
    strcpy(c2, buffer);
```

There is no room in `c2` for the final `\0`.

---

I hope `buffer` and `persona` are not formal parameters to a function. If yes,

```
sizeof(buffer)
```

and

```
sizeof(persona)
```

definitely return a lot less than you expect.

---

About `persona`, why do you make it a pointer, instead of a regular variable?! malloc() should be used only when there is no other chance, exactly because it is dangerous when used improperly.

---

I will tell you if I find more.

Comment: I think there is, that one is working fine, the problem is in the last malloc of the loop in the last iteration (person->dni = malloc(...))

Comment: I was just being nice. There is not. You should use `c2 = malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);` If you use UTF-8 / Unicode / whatever, you may need even more than `+1`

Comment: You do the same mistake in several places, including `(person->dni = malloc(...))`. The message you receive is a very likely outcome of allocating insufficient memory.

Comment: I've added the output to the question, anyway, if that were the case, strdup should work, right? And doesn't

Comment: If you write at the wrong memory addresses, nothing will work deterministically. Once the memory is corrupted at least once, the behavior of everything is assumed to be random. Please make the corrections I told you about, and then see what happens.

Comment: Done, same output, I've added the declaration at the top of the code

Comment: I mean in my code, I'll update here now. Is a pointer cause I've to send it to the client with RPC and that only works with pointers.

Comment: Did you verify ALL `malloc()`s that they allocate enough memory?

Comment: If you have to send a pointer, then take the address of the variable with the `&` operator

Comment: Please add the new code below the original code, otherwise the answers will be meaningless in the end.

Comment: Added the new code (overwritted the previous one, but is just the + 1 to the strlen) Added the structs definitions

Comment: I'm stupid, I was using sizeof(persona) instead of sizeof(facturar) which is the struct itself, ty for your help @virolino